# How to pass string interpolation code to Rails Application Template CODE block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heredoc

According to [Rails Application Templates](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_application_templates.html#vendor-lib-file-initializer-filename-data-nil-block) this is how one can write ruby code into the file:

```
file 'path/to/my_file.rb', <<-CODE
  class Object
    def not_nil?
      !nil?
    end

    def not_blank?
      !blank?
    end
  end
CODE
```

However when I try to add code containing string interpolation between `<<-CODE` and `CODE`, it fails on its first occurrence.

My `file` call:

```
file 'lib/person.rb', <<-CODE
# frozen_string_literal: true

class Person
  def initialize(first_name, last_name)
    @full_name = "#{first_name.capitalize} #{last_name.capitalize}#"
  end
end
CODE
```

Error message:

> template.rb:50:in `apply`: undefined local variable or method `first_name` for Rails::Generators::AppGenerator:0x00005557a8d85090 (NameError)

My understanding is that the template generator tries to execute the interpolated code.

What I tried was simply escaping the `"` double quotes, like:

```
file 'lib/person.rb', <<-CODE
# frozen_string_literal: true

class Person
  def initialize(first_name, last_name)
    @full_name = \"#{first_name.capitalize} #{last_name.capitalize}#\"
  end
end
CODE
```

but it did not help, resulting in exactly the same error.

How can I approach this?

Comment: You could've escaped the `#` instead, not the `"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use heredoc *with* string interpolation, which obviously fails on the attempt to interpolate `first_name`. To prevent the heredoc string interpolation, use `FOO<<-'CODE'` instead:

```
file 'lib/person.rb', <<-'CODE'
# frozen_string_literal: true

class Person
  def initialize(first_name, last_name)
    @full_name = "#{first_name.capitalize} #{last_name.capitalize}#"
  end
end
CODE
```

Comment: Supercool, thanks for help, it worked, I'll accept in 7 minutes!